# why the function which escapes to infinity from one side attains minimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

I have been reading [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271968/1-s2.0-S0021782409X00073/1-s2.0-S0021782409000579/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIAjDKzSRFbBUJmnRwoegdZyexqXnnAHZWpd6bPxM6sueAiB25A5IOTGKIVUZsmZP9Gg%2FZp0AopTJfOAMxGBMfCs3CirbBAjq%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMbcVrWkfE5bAnJKeyKq8EPJxFvEv3SIcTta1a2RpnaWIZzBLC4QiNnv3vWg%2BJksg2oVXLQnyv2IZqd8tIXU%2FKrJFw9FhW3X1N%2FxdKA0VUf2AW12Q82Zykk6Il5mRYcaucErX7VUtQF0UvzuHuxIELyvH%2BdQ8NNwN3vrqHPwRQ2vzMKhx%2F7W92h4d8f%2FopvtcSNwNN2JfGIUf%2FpXe%2BgrNbfEBixy1Emu3ZdMHtWN%2FGviwrInrhTFCCSlAYmjUhsa5OpE2GTIgqPIkHl9YfhPKoVqYfr4OTrPHxjQVD6i2hB5lxWhVAK96gUi7Wg8lxz3%2FCqxv8y5o3wdGASDQZWd3J5pMd%2FJz8NQuShVszs%2BjfmYuVR%2BN5YG4cTlj5UwJO%2BurcOXUpvgr9aAdsSBF%2BGPpahxlTyxEdNG2JGb%2BbsxlpUyp7z1UUKft%2Fh6jh1TZWybGpIZcyHniwzA80E%2FZZeGu2IAjF6Z0uzaVbelljnEzqIdfAuDh%2FaWKZFgOyZEP5VxFcbVjX3QizcfH94IfVTucLWWACIgkdVSzkYwxo7nJCk6Gud%2Btj37LNmc24SbPm24YD3cXcMSreyno8ZlAhF66dCh%2BDv7OnVyrJItiLvm8QXViRk6FCnpUGKOhH2JrVGIxWONezgSUPXgkqxmx8j0%2FsYIbDba%2F1RpByEpgPAEfJ0yD2twT97WiFB4NIytemqoLNbi04U%2BvUJ8oCuOQnCq8NjAiWrv5rjNsVQBLlH0K7V6Sih6b5szaoJDX7NIsV0zCpseOTBjqqAW82N0VX%2BEL3wjg87nbmlETENct4CvTsxE6pIJeIxbY6UWE6VJp9kaSfKt6TUKuLJRAljMuA798uL01i5wGfYE7sMfFATG3oB56McVQucpXl%2FgN9K38xNwWVCvGnYavwrK0H4ZquLTcFcbt9c2SUPtRZ1lY7gowKaNBnn3MaSSHXCtQiu1kJDeh%2FIqusHYL9OnVExVyHLYPghrmDw5CeYEyqJFdwcGeY75Y7&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220509T093754Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYWT6WSIVH%2F20220509%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7789fc05d4bcdff1a25568480f36f847341f5db1e534d5fbb3a635f290ee5b93&hash=c4f05aeae80b6e5d1742c60326ab9d9c67b03f7e110170496ead286f93587b5d&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021782409000579&tid=spdf-7468bae4-9e19-4065-9ec5-41ef60f2ffbf&sid=5247aa9b39f6c840c9895c80836b57485eb6gxrqb&type=client&ua=4d565a5853535b5d5707&rr=708975893cde992c). I don't understand the below statement [image]

To be more precise, I don't understand why $F$ attains a minimum. I thought $F$ must escapes to infinity on both sides, and then it
has well-defined minimum infinity, but in the pic, as you see, it escapes to infinity from one side. Let me stress that $q \in \mathbb{R}^d.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another fact you forgot: on the set $\{q\in\mathbb R^d| \|q\|\geq R\}$, the function is bounded from below by $F(0)$.

This, along with the fact that the function diverges to $\infty$ for large values of $\|q\|$, is enough to know it has a minimum.